# Can a 15-passenger van use the bus lane in Montreal?

Tags: driving, buses, montreal, quebec

In Quebec, a 15-passenger van requires a mini-bus licence.  https://saaq.gouv.qc.ca/en/road-safety/modes-transportation/in-a-fifteen-passenger-van/what-the-law-says/

So I'm wondering if 15-passenger vans are allowed to use the bus lanes in Montreal, specifically.  Of particular interest would be the Champlain Bridge bus lane.

I know that Aeronavette from Sherbrooke to Pierre Elliott Trudeau uses 15-passenger vans, but I've never seen one on the bus lane to my memory. https://aeronavette.ca

I'm also pretty sure that the Greyhound buses (full buses) do use that lane, so I think it's not restricted to the Montreal Transportation system.

So are 15-passenger vans allowed to use the bus lanes, and if so, what are the requirements (example minimum passengers, commercial usage, etc.)

Answer (score 15):

The [Quebec Highway Safety Code](http://legisquebec.gouv.qc.ca/en/ShowDoc/cs/C-24.2) contains the following definitions (italics mine):

> - **“bus”** means a motor vehicle, *other than a minibus,* designed for the transportation of more than nine occupants at a time and used mainly for that purpose or equipped with devices to secure wheelchairs against movement;
>
> ...
>
> - **“minibus”** means a motor vehicle having two axles with single wheels and equipped with not more than five rows of seats for the transportation of more than nine occupants at a time, or equipped with devices to secure wheelchairs against movement;

As the law distinguishes between a "bus" and a "minibus" in this way — in particular, a "minibus" is specifically not a "bus" under the Code — I suspect that minibuses would not be allowed in lanes reserved for "buses" only.

Comment: I tried to up-vote (I don't have sufficient reputation) because this does make sense, but since cities (I'm not sure about Montreal per se) have minibuses for their transport, it would surprise me if these were excluded from using the bus lane.

Comment: Even if you quote the legal definition of 'bus' and 'minibus' here, it does not really answer the question wether a minibus is allowed to use the reserved lanes or not.

Comment: But bus lanes are not covered in that code, so its definition of *bus* may not be relevant.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni no – minibuses have also more than 9 seats, and are excluded from being buses.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Oops sorry you are right, I read that wrong. :(

Comment: The fact that specific definitions are used in one statute doesn't mean the same definitions hold true in statutes from a different authority. City bylaws about bus lanes don't seem to ever address the definitions.

Comment: So I have two exactly opposite answers up-voted the same.  Both are opinions/interpretations.  I guess the only way to be sure is contact the city, or the SAAQ (or try it and contest the ticket, prn :) )?  Are bus lanes strictly a municipal jurisdiction, or is there part of the provincial code that covers them, with definitions, that I have not found?

Comment: Most jurisdictions work on some variation of "smallest inconsistencies". They'll prefer a definition from the same statute over a that from another statute, lacking that they'll prefer definitions from the same authority, then from higher authorities, etc. "Plain english" is generally used as a last resort. I can't tell if there is any _more_ relevant redefinition that the one Michael provided, but it looks like this might be correct.

Answer (score 12):

There reserved lanes are not just for buses. Taxis are allowed too. Here is the [official statement](https://rtm.quebec/en/trip-planner/bus/reserved-lanes) which is valid for the greater Montreal region.

As you can see, it does not say *minibus* which are a different category of vehicle. Considering that a taxi as bus is allowed but both are commercial passenger vehicles, I would be very surprised if they would fine a minibus for using that lane. On some lanes, even private carpools are allowed, although those are clearly marked with a *carpool* sign in addition to the usual *diamond* shape.

Comment: I have up-voted because this makes a lot of sense.  However, minibuses are by default commercial vehicles as well, and must have an "A" plate just like buses.  There are certain exceptions when using them as personal vehicles, but that's not the default. Also some cities (I'm not sure about Montreal per se) use minibuses as well, and I'd be surprised if they were *not* allowed in the bus lane in that case.  Your sentence about "taxi as bus is allowed" is a little unclear to me.

Comment: Sorry: I read your sentence wrong.  I thought you said "would be fine" instead of "would fine".  So you're saying that you suspect it would be OK?  Regardless, I'd like to be able to get some official documents to prove it one way or the other.

Comment: Yes. I do feel it would be OK since those are intended for speeding up public transport which I think a minibus shuttle would count.

Comment: OK. Thanks!  I just wish I could find some official source for this.